# Git bash. Найти commit, из которого создана ветка

Tags: git, git-bash, branch

У меня есть git-репозиторий, в нём 2 ветки (`master` и `foo`). Ветка `foo` создана из `master`, в ней есть свои коммиты. В `master` также были сделаны коммиты, которых нет в ветке `foo`. Выглядит это примерно вот так:

```
        D--H--I--J (foo)
       /
A--B--C--E--F--G (master)
```

**Мне нужна команда для git-bash, которая сможет, находясь в ветке `foo`, найти коммит, из которого была сделана ветка `foo`. (В схеме это коммит С)**

Я перечитал половину документации по `$ git log`, научился многому, но этих знаний нехватает.
Вот так можно найти все коммиты до "С", а именно `D--H--I--J`:

`$ git log master.. --oneline`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конкретно по Вашей ситуации подойдёт `git merge-base foo master`, т.к. у Вас только одна общая фиксация (`C`).

---

Если же граф не такой простой (т.е. у двух веток несколько общих фиксаций), то проще всего искать визуально. Есть ещё и консольное решение, которое описано в ответе на вопрос [Finding a branch point with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527234/finding-a-branch-point-with-git), но оно довольно специфичное, на мой взгляд.

Comment: Это сработало, но не так как нужно. В боевом репозитории, конечно же, были и другие ветки, которые слили в `master`, и эта команда находит не то, что нужно. Если сам смогу найти решение, то обязательно поделюсь с Вами.

Comment: @Артем_М, обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо! Посмотрел ссылку на аналогичный вопрос - это дало нужно понимание.

Answer (score 1):

```
git merge-base master new_branch
```